# What permissions are required for a Release Management 2013 vNext release using Powershell

Tags: powershell-remoting, ms-release-management

I've configured the deployment to a web server using a service account. On the target machine remote powershell is enabled and the account has been added to the Remote Management Users group.

I initiate a release and the following error occurs. If I add the service account to the local Administrators group on the web server then it succeeds. I can reproduce the same error by remoting into the web server, under the service account, and attempting to call `get-service`.

```
System.AggregateException: 
Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges.
 CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId :System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
 ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer '.'. This operation might require other privileges.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.AcquireMutexOwnerShip(String serviceName, String destinationPath, Int64 deploymentHeartbeatTimeoutSec)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
```

Does anyone know the minimum permissions required for a service account to get this working? I want to avoid adding the account to the Administrators group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some background information:
Rather than just executing your Powershell deployment script against the target server using PSRemoting, it uses PSRemoting to install a Windows Service (`VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe`) on the target server. This service then runs your deployment script locally, and the MSRM server regularly polls this Windows service (see [here](http://blogs.infosupport.com/ms-release-management-speeding-up-component-deployment-time/)) to see if it is finished deploying.

I suspect this strange setup has something to do with avoiding the [double-hop issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx) - so that it allows your script to make a 2nd hop from the target server to another server, e.g. for a webservice call.

So you'll need enough permissions to install that Windows service, and [according to this post](https://superuser.com/questions/91908/what-are-the-minimum-user-permissions-required-to-install-a-windows-service), that means administrative permissions.